# How to define the __len__ method for PyTorch Dataloader when I have separate length datasets?

Tags: python, pytorch, dataloader

I'm currently loading in my data with one single dataset class. Within the dataset, I split the train, test, and validation data separately. For example:

```
class Data():
    def __init__(self):
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        with open(file=file_name, mode='r') as f:
            self.data = f.readlines()

        self.train = self.data[:checkpoint]
        self.valid = self.data[checkpoint:halfway]
        self.test = self.data[halfway:]
```

Many of the details have been omitted for the sake of readability. Basically, I read in one big dataset and make the splits manually.

My question is arising from how to override the `__len__` method when the lengths of my train, valid, and test data all differ?

The reason I want to do this is because I want to keep the split data in one single class, and I also want to create separate Dataloaders for each, and so something like:

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.train)
```

wouldn't be appropriate for `self.test` and `self.valid`.

Perhaps I'm fundamentally misunderstanding the Dataloader, but how should I approach this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most appropriate method to get the length of each split, is to simply use:

```
# Number of training points
len(self.train)

# Number of testing points
len(self.test)

# Number of validation points
len(self.valid)
```

Alternatively, if you want to refer to the length of splits for a particular instance of your object:

```
data = Data()
print(len(data.train))
print(len(data.test))
print(len(data.valid))
```

`__len__` allows you to implement the way you want to count the elements of an object. Therefore, I would implement it as follows, and use the aforementioned calls to get the counts per split:

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.data)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause issues when creating my Dataloader objects for each setting? If I define `__len__` in the way that you proposed, then I could simply do `return len(self.data)` rather than adding the three, couldn't I? Perhaps I need to look into it in more depth, but I've never seen an explicit call to the `__len__` method when declaring Dataloader objects.

Comment: @Seankala I didn't see that you initialise `self.data` too. I've updated my answer.